# Show IP addresses of the last 20 users to login to my server

Tags: logs, accounts

Show the IP address of the computer that the 20 users who logged in to the server, in UNIX?

I used `last -20` to show the last 20 user logins. Now I need to see the IP address for those users.

Comment: Please [edit] and explain what you're asking. What users? What server? Do you want the IPs of the remote computers that users are logging in from? What operating system? Do you actually mean UNIX or is it Linux? Are you just looking for the `w` command?

Comment: Please elaborate. Your first language may not be English (nor is it mine), but at least make some effort.

Comment: `who` shows you the users currently logged on.

Comment: Unix  and ,IPs of the remote computers that users are logging in from to the server i used the last -20 to show the last 20 users now i need to see the IP address for those users? thank you

Comment: If you know actual command you need, than you can always try learning more of it by using `man <command>`, or sometimes `<command> --help`.

Answer (score 21):

If you need information of 20 last logged-in users you can use:

```
last -20 -w
```

to display full hosts, or

```
last -20 -i
```

to display IP numbers.

Comment: @hdabaja If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.